# You have already activated rack 1.6.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.5.5.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to rebuild my gemlock file by removing it and running bundle install.

I have tried to remove the gem rack 1.6.1 and got this message:

```
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    rack-1.6.1

actionpack-4.2.1 depends on rack (~> 1.6)
```

I have done bundle update but it only updates rack to version 1.5.5

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: just run `bundle update`

Comment: Either you have something like `gem 'rack' '~1.5.5'` in your Gemfile (then probably remove the version spec) or, more probably, something else has this dependency on such old rack version. Go through your `Gemfile.lock` and look for all rack version specifications. Some of the dependent gems probably require such old version.

Comment: I ran bundle update. However this did not fix the issue. I looked inside the Gemfile.lock file and saw that rack (1.5.5) was there. I changed it to 1.6.1 and now it works without the error. I'm not saying this is an answer because I'm not supposed to change this file manually. When I run bundle update it puts rack back to 1.5.5. Why won't it update itself when I do bundle update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that I was using Rails 4.1.2 which used Rack 1.5.5. When I updated my Rails app to use Rails 4.2.6 the later version of rack was loaded and this conflict in the gems was solved.